# Webpack - include css only in development bundle (not production)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

When I create my production bundle I do not require any stylesheets in javascript, they are included in index.html. The stylesheets are compiled with a grunt watch from sass to a bundle.css.

While developing I use webpack dev server. Now I want to include the css in the javascript bundle for hot module replacement, but *without changing any existing javascript files*.

The dev server is using dedicated index.html and webpack.config files, so preferably that's where I include the css bundle. Is this possible?

Maybe it's worth mentioning that I'm using React.

Comment: You want to use hot module replacement with CSS?

Comment: Yes. For the record it works if I simply require bundle.css from my main javascript file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **Answer:** It looks like you can change the `entry[]` of `webpack.config` ([example](https://github.com/coryhouse/react-slingshot/blob/master/webpack.config.dev.js)), to access a different `.js` file. Try creating referencing two different `.js` entry files for your respective `webpack.config` files, to `import` a different CSS file or omit the `import` line entirely. This compromises DRY, but does what you want.
2. React shouldn't make any difference.
3. Hot module is a red herring; it's implemented as a plugin, independently of the above:

   ```
   plugins: [
   ...
       new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin());
   ],
   ```
4. Omitting the CSS module loader in `webpack.config.dev` wouldn't work.

   ```
   module: {
     loaders: [
   ...
       {test: /(\.css|\.scss)$/, loaders: ['style', 'css?sourceMap', 'sass?sourceMap']}
     ]
   }
   ```

   because it would cause a parse error in `import 'path/to/my.css'` in `index.js`